# Material-ui-next Popover on GridListTile

Tags: react-redux, material-ui

Has anyone successfully managed to create a popover on a GridList tile item?  From https://material-ui-next.com/demos/grid-list/ I've created an 'advanced' Grid List (horizontally scrolling GridList), but as soon as I try to add popovers, the horizontal styling functionality seems to be discarded, and the popover still does not show (with no errors in console).
It simply doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just an update: with the release of **Material-UI v1** this still seems to be an issue, so the workaround I have is to grab the mapped item and display in a separate `CardMedia` item, below the (horizontally styled) `GridList`.